# Redirect an url(view) in js dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, wcf

I have a MVC 3 application. I want to display the result I just created.

Some of the code for Controller and View.

```
  public ActionResult ViewGenerated(string Number, string ClientID)
    {
        // get a list of inmate id's and pins from batch number
        string url = HttpContext.Request.Url.ToString();
        int client;
        client = int.Parse(ClientID);
        int batch = int.Parse(Number);

        var list = (from a in aContext.aDetail
                    select a).ToList();
        // set this to the object collection
        ViewBag.x = list;
        return View();
    }
```

Then View

```
@foreach (var r in ViewBag.x)
    { 
        <tr>
            <td>@r.ID</td>
            <td>@r.Name</td>
        </tr>
```

In my javascript code I call a WCF and return the number and I try to pass it the controller??

```
function GenerateX() {
    // blah blah
    $.getJSON('/some service', function (response) {
    });
    // What I want is to get the number from the service then redirect the url to the view 
    $(this).dialog('close'); // Close it
}
```

I used a jquery dialog to call "GenerateX".

I am not sure how to do it, I am not strong on this area.

Many thanks.

**updated:**

```
 $.getJSON('/Services/InService.svc/blah/GeneratePINs/').success(viewPins);
    // return "Number" here and want to pass it to controller.
    $(this).dialog('close'); // Close it
}

function viewPins(data) {
    var clientId = $("#clientIds").val();
    alert(clientId); // code not reach here
    window.open('/WebAdminOrion/blah/ViewGeneratedPINs?Number=' + data + '?&ClientID=' + clientId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `window.location.href`

Ex.

```
window.location.href = '/controllername/actionname';
```

or

```
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("actionname")';
```

Comment: Suppose the service returns an integer, how to get it in js?

Comment: You have to check the response parameter

Answer (score 0):

See this:

HTML (for javascript unobstructive):

```
<!-- Constant or key in the "web.config" having the service route -->
<input type="hidden" id="service-url" value="@ConstUrlService" />
<input type="hidden" id="action-url" value="@Url.Action("action", "controller")" />
```

For best implementation to get URL for service, see [jQuery AJAX calls to a WCF REST Service](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Apr/21/jQuery-AJAX-calls-to-a-WCF-REST-Service)

JS (external file):

```
function GenerateX() {

    var dialog = this; 

    // blah blah
    $.getJSON($('#service-url').val(), function (response) {

       /*
       the call to "close" must be here, because the "ajax" is asynchronous 
       */

       /*
       This answer has to be the number, and could have a response status 
       for example Ok (true/false) 
       */

       if (response.Ok && response.Number != 0) {

            $(dialog).dialog('close'); // Close it
            window.location = $('#action-url').val() + '?Number=' + response.Number + '&ClientID=' + response.ClientID; 
       }
       else {

            alert('problem');
       }

    }).fail(function() {

       /* 
       for error
       */ 

       alert('call error');

    });
};
```

Comment: 1 viewPins != ViewPins javascript is case sensitive, 2 "}" after "$(this).dialog('close');" What is closing?

Comment: closing a jquery dialog. I had a button click event to call this function.

Comment: Where to call your action "ViewGenerated" in your javascript code?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

```
window.open('/WebAdminOrion/blah/ViewGeneratedPINs?Number=' + data + '&ClientID=' + clientId);
```

There is one question marker. Removed it then reslove it.